# R system command on file name with spaces stored in network disk (windows)

Tags: r, windows, system

I want to count the lines in a file. The file is stored in a network disc and the filename contains space. I am using the following command which does not work

```
system('wc -l "\\\\network1\\test file.txt"')
```

and neither

```
system('wc -l \\\\network1\\test file.txt')
```

However these worked on files on network disc (with no spaces in filename) or when the filename contains space (but located in normal directories).

```
system('wc -l \\\\network1\\testfile.txt')
system('wc -l "test file.txt")
```

How can I achieve the above?

PS: I have `Rtools` installed for these system command.

Comment: `wc` is not part of a standard Windows installation as far as I remember. Where does yours come from?

Comment: It comes from `Rtools`.

Comment: Does the command work when you run it from a system command line (`cmd`)?

Comment: Yes, it does work using `cmd`.